# Update.php: Page not found

Tags: 7

Currently using D7 (specifically the Commerce Kickstart installation profile). When trying to reach update.php, I get a "Page Not Found" error. I also noticed that the url Drupal is trying to reach is /core/update.php.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the `.htaccess` file from 8.x instead of the one from 7.x?
The directory structure of Drupal core changed from 7.x to 8.x, and 8.x includes additional mod_rewrite rules to redirect to the changed locations of `update.php` and `install.php`

Answer (score 1):

This type of redirect to `/core/` is likely to originate from a `.htaccess` file from Backdrop or Drupal 8+. The problem can occur even when using the `.htaccess` file from Drupal 7, if the browser has previously seen a Backdrop or D8+ site running at the same URL.

Those `.htaccess` files use a `301` Redirect (permanent redirect) which is remembered by the web browser. In this case it's necessary to clear (or temporarily disable) the cache in the browser, and then try the request again.